# Can a Javascript bookmarklet overlay an image on a web page?

Tags: javascript, css, bookmarklet

Can a bookmarklet be used to overlay an image on a web page? Not as a pop-up, but as a image positioned by CSS and with a high z-index to display on top of other elements. And without a mask i.e., Shadowbox or similar jQuery effect. Just an image from a URL and positioned in the bottom left hand corner of the browser window.

This is what I have so far, but it may be the wrong direction to be going:

```
javascript:(function(){document.write("<style type='text/css'>body {background-image:url(http://example.com/image.png); position: absolute; left:50px; top:300px; z-index:9999;}</style>");})()
```

I have a JS function that works as a bookmarklet to change the case of text on the page, and now I'd like to be able to show an image when the bookmarklet is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a *background* image for the body won't help if you want the image to *overlay* the page. Also, `document.write` can't be used directly to add CSS styles.

What you probably want to do is add a new `img` element to the page, and give it `absolute` or `fixed` positioning, along with a high `z-index`.

Here's an example that adds the SO logo to the corner of the window, using `fixed` positioning:

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML += '<img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" style="position: fixed; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; z-index: 1000">';})();
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize I had the background image call in there. That works great for the SO logo and for the image I want to use. But... sometimes in IE with a page scrollable content, the image ends up at the bottom of the page out of view. Don't know how that would be fixed. Doesn't seem to be consistent, either.

Comment: Well, IE6 doesn't support `position:fixed`, so that could be your problem. There is a workaround for it, but it's really only useful when building a site from scratch, since it can break a lot of other CSS. Writing cross-browser bookmarklets is a difficult problem.

Comment: It was IE8, but it must be a site-specific thing with complex CSS, and this will be used specifically on a simpler site. So it doesn't really matter. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think document.write would be appropriate here; why not create a new img element and append it to the body?

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'urlhere';
// TODO: set position and whatnot
body.appendChild(img);
```